# (As you mentioned / pointed out) and (Thank you for mentioning / pointing out)

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

I know that when you 'point something out' you have already found something important with that and would like the listener(s) know about it too in order to draw their attention to it.
Now, please imagine in a conference someone is giving a speech to the audience presented there and when he wants to give his/her place to another speech maker for a short time. When the second one is going to continue the speech around the same topic, can use some **fixed statements** like the ones below. I would appreciate it if you let me know that which one sounds correct and which one doesn't and why:

> **1.a)** Thank you for **mentioning that** Mr. Smith... 
>  
>   **2.a)** Thank you for **pointing that out** Mr. Smith...

And

> **2.b)** As Mr Smith **mentioned**... 
>   **2.b)** As Mr Smith **pointed out**...

Please note that, in spite of including the same elements, this thread is different from my [other question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221319/point-out-vs-mention) asked previously. Here, I'm asking about some "fixed statements" rather than the mere usage.

I way wondering if someone could explain it to me that how the two sentences of each group differ in meaning?

Answer (score -2):

I will go with 2b.

I feel we don’t have to thank the first speaker for mentioning, as it was a part of his presentation or speech already.

If the first speaker has mentioned something out of the box or pointed out something very important then using 1a and 1b will make sense.